# How to externalize language properties and templates from main application?

Tags: java, git

I'm using custom (`xml`, `xslt`, `properties`) files to add configuration logic to my application.  They are read at startup and can be dynamically reloaded calling a specific `webservice` endpoint of the app.

The purpose of those files does not matter for my question. Let's assume they just represent locale/language properties.

Currently any files are placed inside the `war` in `/src/main/resources`, and during build automatically and by default copied to `/WEB-INF/classes` by `maven`.

Problem: I want other users to modify these files, without having to touch the main project (eg the language files are simple enough that non-developers should be able to modify them at purpose).

Question is: how could I best separated those files from my main project?
Putting them in a database is not option!

I could think of the following approaches, but none of them seems really satisfying:

- create a **git repository** that only contains xml templates. Then include a link to that repository from into my `/src/main/resources` folder and check out **resursively**.

  PRO: Then the templates are automatically picked up on building.

  CON: I have to explicit call recursive checkout in git. And I have to rebuild the app even if only templates changed.
- create a **library** containing the xml templates (this could also be just a repository containing the xml files, plus the java/maven files to build that library). Then I could build that library and just replace the one in the application server.

  PRO: I just have to rebuild the template jar.

  CON: I probably have to restart the app to take the updated library into account.
- create a **simple folder** on the application server machine, outside of the app itself. Use a git repository that again only contains the xml templates. And check them out to the production server folder.

  PRO: I could monitor that folder from my app and reload the templates dynamically.

  CON: I have to explicit perform a checkout on the production system

Could I do better? If not, which approach would you chose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I created a simple `.war` project containing the configuration files in `src/main/WEB-INF/`. The project can be deployed to `tomcat`, and the files can then be accessed relative to `CATALINA_BASE/webapps/` from other applications. Or even directly through the `localhost:8080` webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I am using config.xml file (which content can be changed) to send some changing data to project from the xml file placed next to the jar file

Java code:

```
public class DomParser {

private static File configFile;
private static DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory;
private static DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
private static Document document;
private static NodeList nList;
private static Element eElement;

public static String build() {
    return getElement("Application", "Build");
}



private static String getElement(String tagname, String name) {
    try {
        configFile = new File("Config.xml");
        dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = dBuilder.parse(configFile);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        nList = document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
        Node nNode = nList.item(0);
        eElement = (Element) nNode;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return eElement.getElementsByTagName(name).item(0).getTextContent();
}
```

xml file (which is used to send text "AwesomeBuild" to jar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<APP>
    <Application>
        <Build>AwesomeBuild</Build>     
    </Application>
</APP>
```

Hope it is sth you are looking for and will help